# sychronise SQlite on my android phone and Oracle on my pc

Tags: android, oracle, sqlite

I've been looking arround for a while on how to synchronise an sqlite on my phone and the oracle database in an app on my pc ((and the other way arround)) , I don't want to use internet. I just need to connect both the pc and the phone via USB. can you please help me?

Comment: You **need** a WebService. Which can be used on an `intranet`. No need to use `internet`.

Comment: How do I create an intranet ?

Comment: Far tooooooo broad. In synthesis: it's your existing network, with a web-like interface.